# Why does fs.mkdir(); yield an ENOENT error with really long directory names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, directory

I'm using Windows 7 and Node.js.

Example:

```
fs.mkdir(__dirname + '/users/' + 'asdlfjlasdfjlsdajflasdkjflksadjflasdkjflasdkjflsadkjflaskdjflasdkjfaslkdjfaslkdjfasldkjfsaldkjfaslkdjflasdkjflaskdfjalskdjflsdakjflasd%3Bkjflaksdjfklasdfja%3Bsdlkfjasldkfjlsadkfjklsadjfasldkfjlsadkjflasdkjflasdkjfasdlfjlasdfjlsdajflasdkjflksadjflasdkjflasdkjflsadkjflaskdjflasdkjfaslkdjfaslkdjfasldkjfsaldkjfaslkdjflasdkjflaskdfjalskdjflsdakjflasd%3Bkjflaksdjfklasdfja%3Bsdlkfjasldkfjlsadkfjklsadjfasldkfjlsadkjflasdkjflasdkjfasdlfjlasdfjlsdajflasdkjflksadjflasdkjflasdkjflsadkjflaskdjflasdkjfaslkdjfaslkdjfasldkjfsaldkjfaslkdjflasdkjflaskdfjalskdjflsdakjflasd%3Bkjflaksdjfklasdfja%3Bsdlkfjasldkfjlsadkfjklsadjfasldkfjlsadkjflasdkjflasdkjfasdlfjlasdfjlsdajflasdkjflksadjflasdkjflasdkjflsadkjflaskdjflasdkjfaslkdjfaslkdjfasldkjfsaldkjfaslkdjflasdkjflaskdfjalskdjflsdakjflasd%3Bkjflaksdjfklasdfja%3Bsdlkfjasldkfjlsadkfjklsadjfasldkfjlsadkjflasdkjflasdkjf', function(err) {
  if (err && err.code == 'EEXIST') {
    // do nothing
  } else if (err) throw(err)
});
```

I have an inkling it has to do with Windows limiting size of directory paths. I've read a few varying accounts of what the actual limit is, but it seems like it's relatively small.

But seriously, why is ENOENT the error code? Is there a way to make sure that in this case the error is because the directory name/path is too long. Is ENOENT only returned by mkdir(); in the case that the directory is too long? I just feel like there should be a better code than ENOENT, because in my (very limited) experience it means that the directory does not exist, not that it can't exist.

P.S. I've somehow managed to make a pretty long directory name, (not quite as long as the one above) on my computer using mkdir(). When I try to delete the file by right clicking, Windows Explorer invariably crashes, and when I use the 'delete' key or drag the file to the Recycle Bin nothing happens. Also, 'del' in the command line says that the name is too long. Any solutions to getting this folder off of my computer?

(The 'users' directory does exist.)

Comment: It probably is the Windows limit of 260 chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mkdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) is a POSIX function, and indeed it's specification says that if the supplied name is too long, it should return `ENAMETOOLONG`.

Windows is not a POSIX system, though. It does provide a number of wrappers for common POSIX functions - for example there is a [mkdir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235326.aspx) function which MS says is deprecated in favour of the ISO C++ compliant [_mkdir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx) function. My guess is that the former actually just calls the latter.

The documentation for the MS implementation of _mkdir only specifies two possible error codes: EEXIST and ENOENT.

My guess is that the implementation of mkdir in windows calls the underlying Win32 [CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) function, then mapped all of the possible error codes from that function into one of the two they have chosen to return from _mkdir.

Node.js is not really playing a role in this. It's `fs` package is itself a wrapper around the POSIX functions. It is returning the error code that it gets from the Win32 mkdir wrapper.

Comment: Yes.  The underlying Win32 error code is `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` which means either the directory doesn't exist or the path is otherwise invalid.  Win32 doesn't distinguish between the two cases, so neither does _mkdir.